# Error while running spark application with Oozie

Tags: apache-spark, oozie

I have a sample Spark application, which runs perfectly fine with `spark-submit`. Now, I want to run the application using Oozie workflow, and when I run the workflow, I get the following error:

```
Launcher exception: org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:167)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:49)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:237)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runSubtask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:380)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runTask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:301)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.access$200(LocalContainerLauncher.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler$1.run(LocalContainerLauncher.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 20 more
```

I do have the paths configured correctly. This is my `workflow.xml` file:

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.1' name='mySparkExample'>
    <start to='spark-node' />
    <action name='spark-node'>
            <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
                    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                    <master>yarn}</master>
                    <name>mySparkExample</name>
                    <class>com.example.App</class>
                    <jar>mySpark/jars/</jar>
                    <arg>myjar.jar</arg>
            </spark>
            <ok to="end" />
            <error to="fail" />
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
            <message>Workflow failed, error
            </message>
    </kill>
    <end name='end' />
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have anything interesting to say about the Oozie **ShareLibs**? E.g. did you include the Spark "system" ShareLib? If yes, which version? If not, where is Oozie supposed to find the Spark assembly?

Comment: Side note: Oozie has come a long way since `uri:oozie:workflow:0.1` /// Other side note: I guess the rogue brace in `<master>yarn}</master>` is a typo.

Comment: Please copy spark-assembly jar to lib where all of your jars files are available. It should be HDFS folder unless you specify `file:///`. Please find below example:                                                                                                                         `oozie hdfs  /user/oozie/JobName/lib/YourJar.jar
oozie hdfs  /user/oozie/JobName/lib/dependent jars
oozie hdfs  /user/oozie/JobName/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.2.2.5.3.0-37-hadoop2.7.3.2.5.3.0-37.jar
oozie hdfs  /user/oozie/JobName/workflow.xml`